# Чтение узлов XML

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется XML вида:

```
<result name="response" numFound="252>
<doc score="1">
<field name="content">
 ...123...
</field>
</doc>
<doc score="2">
<field name="content">
 ...123...
</field>
</doc>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как читать хмылку по узлам (...123...) и каждый узел записывать в отдельный `RichTextBox`! Хпасом пробовал, что не получается!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно считать интересующие узлы из документа LINQ'ом в массив, а уже затем значения из массива использовать при задании текста в RichTextBox. Извлечение значений в массив:

```
XElement result = XElement.Load(@"result.xml");

string[] fields = result
    .Descendants("field")
    .Select(f => f.Value)
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Что я честно не понял !!! Если не трудно можно подроднее!!

Comment: [LINQ to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb387098.aspx).