# как прочесть в c# XML документ?

Tags: c#, xml

Уважаемые знатоки!
как на СиШарпе, прочитать ХМЛ файл такого рода:

```
<ValType Type="Метал">
<Valute Code="XPD">
<Nominal>1 t.u.</Nominal>
<Name>Palladium</Name>
<Value>2393.974</Value>
```

Мне нужно вывести на экран значение.

Comment: Несколько методов. 1)Сериализация. 2) XmlReader 3) XmlDocument 4) Разбор "вручную". 1,2,3 - в MSDN c примерами есть. На SO тоже масса вопросов с ответами по этой теме.

Comment: На SO  1.http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/431356/%d0%a1%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-xml-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0 2.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/89494/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-xml 3.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/576772/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%b8-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-xml

Comment: Сделайте на SO поиск хотя бы так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+%5Bc%23%5D+%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5 Мне кажется что вопросы похожие на ваш уже есть.

Answer (score 2):

Вначале создаёте модель.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData{
    public string DataType {get;set;}
    public string Code {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
}
```

Потом десериализуете XML в неё.
Если XML в файле:

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("data.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    MyData myData = (MyData)serializer.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Если нет передаёте в метод `Deserialize` другой `Stream` или `Reader` (подробнее см. в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.deserialize?view=netframework-4.8))